# How to check if element already exist in an array

Tags: c#, arraylist

I got an `ArrayList` in C#

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
```

now I add a string to it

```
myAL.Add("Hello");
```

How can I now figure out if the String "Hello" exist in the array. I know it's possible to loop over it, but I think there must exist a function or something.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `ArrayList` rather than `List<string>` or `HashSet<string>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the method `Contains` from `System.Collections`

[Microsoft Doc - Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.contains?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ArrayList_Contains_System_Object_)

For your example :

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
myAL.Add("Hello");
if (myAL.Contains("Hello"))
{
    // Do something
}
```